# How can I guarantee alertDialog to disappear automatically every time in Flutter with the correct context?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How can I improve this alert dialog so that it always displays for 1 second then disappears. Sometimes the navigator pop doesn't work on the correct context and "misses" it when code is layered in other widgets. Is there a way to guarantee the correct context? I need a consistent fix and already tried another thread's answer. `barrierDismissible: false,` did not fix this.

```
showAlertDialogTMPCoinsAdded(BuildContext context, String title, String content) {

    Timer timer = Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 1000), (){
      Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
    });
    AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
      title: Text(title),
      content: Image.asset('assets/images/coins.gif'),
    );

  showDialog(
        barrierDismissible: false,
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return alert;
        },
  ).then((value){
    timer.cancel();
  });




}
```

Comment: If you want to display a message for a few seconds, then go away, an alternative is to use a `SnackBar`.

Comment: I just tried your code and it's working fine in my part.

Comment: @RoslanAmir I want a GIF to display, not just a message. In fact, I don't really need any text at all since the gif contains a message

Comment: @NaKib this doesn't seem to work when I'm calling it after an in app purchase is made. There must be a better way to cancel a dialog than just a timer and navigator pop

Comment: To be clear I'm looking to guarantee the context I pop is ONLY the this widget no matter what.